# can I use natural rocks from my property as a 4 foot retaining wall?

Tags: walls

I want to use natural rocks and build it up to about 3 feet.  Will it last if I use concrete/mortar to fill in the gaps?  I am in east Tenn where it freezes in the winter.

Comment: Leave drainage spaces.

Comment: If you bed the rocks well with a good mix that is a start. a cap of flat rocks on top or a mortar cap to help shed the water will help the wall last longer. A strong base is the place where many people don't go far enough a small trench with cement and even a piece of rebar will help the wall be stronger and last all of your days for a free standing wall. If it is a retaining wall it will need weep holes/ drains to prevent the hydraulic water pressure from pushing and breaking the mortar. I did 1 wall 4' high and used strips of chicken wire in the mortar with 1/2" pipes every 5' at the bottom.

Comment: Laying natural rock is a serious pain, when done professionally (like for a chimney, not a gabion wall, which might be a consideration for you). The best way to lay natural rock is to build the wall without mortar, to make certain that it will stand by itself, then mark (number) the rocks (easiest way, left to right, bottom to the top. Then take it all down, and re-lay it using mortar. For larger walls, you would do it in 2 or three foot sections, but since you are only doing a few feet, then that's how the good-job is done. Also, what @EdBeal said above is true.

Comment: This would be better on gardening and landscaping.  You can use a dry stone wall for which there are some excellent answers see http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5860/raised-beds-border-made-of-a-dry-stone-wall/5861?s=9|0.1798#5861